# RLS with the datasets created with excel

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have datasets that has been created using Excel. Now I want to apply Row level security on the dataset. Is there any way to enable RLS to the datasets created by using Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert your files into Power BI Desktop (PBIX) files in order to enable RLS for datasets made with Excel.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls